Azure Durable Function - add custom headers to 202 response in trigger
we are trying to figure out how to alter the default 202 response, and add custom headers on success from called trigger function.
Reason we are trying to do so, is preserving already existing response content and headers e.g.
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Location: http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/abc123?code=XXX

{
"id": "abc123",
"purgeHistoryDeleteUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/abc123?code=XXX",
"sendEventPostUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/abc123/raiseEvent/%7BeventName%7D?code=XXX",
"statusQueryGetUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/abc123?code=XXX",
"terminatePostUri": "http://localhost:7071/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/abc123/terminate?reason=%7Btext%7D&code=XXX"
}

This structure is generated automatically on calling the DurableTaskClient as below:
var response = await orchestrationClient.CreateCheckStatusResponseAsync(request, orchestrationInstanceId);

Is there elegant way to add headers to this response?
We tried:
Simply adding headers - no effect.
response.Headers.Add("myHeader", "myHeaderValue");

Using a middleware approach of implementing IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
Registration:

2 variants

.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(builder =>
 {
     builder.UseWhen<HttpTriggerResponseMiddleware>(context =>
     {
         return context
             .FunctionDefinition
             .InputBindings
             .Values
             .First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type == "httpTrigger";
     });
 })

.ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication(builder =>
{
    builder.UseMiddleware<HttpTriggerResponseMiddleware>();
})


Interceptor:

also tried fiddling with context.GetInvocationResult() - no effect
await next(context) placement might be an issue, however any other placement results in GetHttpresponseData returning null

        public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            await next(context);

            var headers = context.GetHttpResponseData()?.Headers;
            if (headers == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            headers.Add(Constants.RequestConstants.CorrelationId, contextHelper.CorrelationId);
            headers.Add(Constants.RequestConstants.SourceApplication, contextHelper.SourceApplication);
        }

Now, what we found is that anytime we are altering/intercepting the response we see two headers "Location" and "Content-Type" already in place, which are created by DurableTaskClient and described in microsoft documentation.
However, any manual changes have no effect in returned response, YET somehow three more headers are appended eventually somewhere, somehow - "Server", "Date" and "Transfer-Econding".
Note that creating request manually using request.CreateResposne() works, however we lose required/existing response body and headers.
Any hints and advices will be very much appreciated.
Thanks everybody in advance!

Are you using isolated or inprocess function?

I have referred this SO Thread and used middleware to add custom headers in durable function.
public class HttpTriggerResponseMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();

        await next(context);

        context.GetHttpResponseData()?.Headers.Add("myHeader", "myHeaderValue");

    }
}

I am using default isolated durable function code.
I have below code in program.cs file.
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(workerApplication =>
    {
        workerApplication.UseWhen<HttpTriggerResponseMiddleware>((context) =>
        {
            return context.FunctionDefinition.InputBindings.Values
                      .First(a => a.Type.EndsWith("Trigger")).Type == "httpTrigger";
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

You would be able to see the custom header in response header.

